# How to set the text cursor to a specific location on the screen in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, text, location

I'm, trying to write a script in Python that can set a cursor on a specific location in the screen and take values. This is something that on BASIC language would look like this:

```
10 LOCATE 20,10
20 INPUT "Please enter value:", N$
```

I wrote a function to put the cursor at a defined X, Y coordinate at the screen using sys.stdout.write() and it works fine.

Problem is, when I use either input() or sys.stdin.readline(), the echo of the value typed on the screen always appears on position 1, 1 at the upper left side of the screen.

Attached you will find a snapshot of what I'm getting on the screen.

The function I created is as follows:

```
def inputxy(x, y, color, text):
    sys.stdout.write(color)
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (y, x, text))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(WHITE)
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    return n
```

Is there any function in python that can read values and maintain the text cursor on a defined position in the screen or,  what I might be missing in the above function to accomplish that objective?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image: Snapshot of running script]